# Create a shortcode to display the Woocommerce flat rate price as displayed on the checkout

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I would like to create a plugin to add 2 shortcodes to my woocommerce shop so I can add the shipping cost as shortcode in text like this example:

Our shipping costs to Amsterdam is [shipping_cost_1] Euro

So on front end the text will be like this: Our shipping costs to Amsterdam is 6,95 Euro

These are the rates and shortcodes I want to use:

[shipping_cost_1] = flat rate woocommerce shipping cost including VAT for shipping zone 1 (shipping inside Amsterdam)
[shipping_cost_2] = flat rate woocommerce shipping cost including VAT for shipping zone 2 (shipping outside Amsterdam)

For reference, this is where the shipping costs for Amsterdam are displayed on the checkout page:

[image: shipping cost Amsterdam on checkout]

I would like to add the code in the following structure:

// The shortcode function

function shipping_cost_display_1() {

// Get shipping cost from woocommerce

???

// Ad code returned

???

// Register shortcode

add_shortcode('shipping_cost_1', 'shipping_cost_display_1');

Answer (score 0):

just wondering if you checked this article already: [WooCommerce: Show Shipping Rates @ Single Product Page](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-show-shipping-rates-single-product-page/)?

Basically you can get the shipping zones with a simple command:

```
WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
```

Once you have them, you can loop over the array and find rates inside ($instance['cost']).

The following should do the trick for you - of course change "amsterdam" to your desired zone name:

```
function shipping_cost_display_1() {
    $zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
    foreach ( $zones as $zone_id => $zone ) {
        if ( "amsterdam" !== $zone['zone_name'] ) continue;
        $zone_shipping_methods = $zone['shipping_methods'];
        foreach ( $zone_shipping_methods as $index => $method ) {
            $instance = $method->instance_settings;
            return $instance['cost'];
        }
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'shipping_cost_1', 'shipping_cost_display_1' );
```

There is also to say that the same shortcode could be used to return the two rates, by using a shortcode parameter.